# ajax loading query in separate div

Tags: ajax, html

My problem is: when a user presses a key, a div will be shown with all the users who have a firstname starting with the users input. It's mandatory that I need to select something. 
The problem is when user enter an invalid entry instead of selecting it from the showned div. How to validate it

```
function getDcode(str)
{
    document.getElementById("codes").style.display = "block";
    if (str.length==0)
    {
      document.getElementById("codes").innerHTML="";
      return;
    }
    xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
    if (xmlhttp==null)
    {
      alert ("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP!");
      return;
    }
    var url="<?php print WEB_URL?>load_code/";
    url = url + str;
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

Comment: please consider formatting your code . So that will be easy to read

Answer (score 0):

I believe want to have an auto-complete text field?,

If yes I suggest try jquery auto-complete

http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/autocomplete.htm

Comment: The problem is when user enter an invalid entry instead of selecting it from the showned div. How to validate it

Comment: You should always validate user input either on client&server or server only.

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting this...

You do want to have manual entry but are allowing the users to press a key?

I am not sure if that is possible to implement.

Comment: No actually its allowed to enter the starting letters but after displaying the list of items with the starting letter as the user keyed, they need to select it from the div. instead if the user let go to another field with junk info in the code. then how to alert the user.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution, using jQuery. Customize to use your  own class/regex

> Odell, Den. "Chapter 8 - Form
>   Controls". Pro JavaScript RIA
>   Techniques: Best Practices,
>   Performance, and Presentation. Apress.
>   © 2009. Books24x7.
>   http://common.books24x7.com/book/id_31169/book.asp
>   (accessed December 29, 2009)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").keypress(function(e) {
        switch(e.target.className) {
            case "numerical":
                if (e.key.match(/[^0-9]/g)) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
                break;

            case "email":
                // The following regular expression matches all characters not
                // permitted within an email address
                if (e.key.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9@!#$%&'*+-\/=?^_{}~.]+/g)) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

edit: modified the above in order to work properly with jQuery's events